# intersection of a ruby array and the keys of a hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Is it possible to get the intersection of an array and just the keys of a hash?

I know that the `&` operator returns the intersection of two arrays, but I'd like to use the values instead of the `value + key` combination.

Let's say, I have an array and a hash :

```
a1 = [ 'test1', 'test2', 'test3' ]
a2 = { 'test3' => 'value3', 'test4'=>'value4', 'test5'=>'value5' }
```

is there a way to return `value3` from these?

Comment: The second one isn't a valid syntax. I'm assuming the second one should be a hash, but you should clarify your question more.

Comment: Pierre, I've taken the liberty of submitting an edit to your question so that it clearly asks for the intersection of an array and the values of a hash.  Previously, you were getting down-voted for two reasons: 1) your question implied that a hash was an array, and used the array syntax to define a hash which would throw an error, and 2) your expected result would have actually given the intersection of your hash's keys and the array, when it seems like you wanted to compare the hash values to an array.

Comment: It's not clear from your example if you want to match keys or values.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say you want the intersection of the array and the values, and then you say that that intersection should be `'value3'`, but actually, the intersection of `a1` and `a2`'s values is empty, there are no common elements between `'test1', 'test2', 'test3'` and `'value3', 'value4', 'value5'`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag actually, I didn't, the title has been edited by someone else who assumed it was about values. I'm using keys, but it's basically the same (see the answer below, just replaced .values by .keys)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

given

```
arr = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
hsh = {:key1 => 'value3', :key2=>'value4', :key3=>'value5'}
```

you can convert hsh to an array of values with the .values method and use the & operator to compare the hash values with an array.

```
arr & hsh.values

=> ["value3"]
```

Comment: @PierreOliverTran No problem.  Try to edit your question more carefully next time, and you won't get so many downvotes ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is probably the most intuitive way I can think of to do what you're asking:

```
a1 = [ 'test1', 'test2', 'test3' ]
a2 = { 'test3' => 'value3', 'test4'=>'value4', 'test5'=>'value5' }

(a1 & a2.keys).map { |e| a2[e] }
#=> ["value3"]
```

That is you want the intersection of `a1` and the keys from `a2`. You can then use map to perform the lookup on each key found in the intersection to return the value.

Answer (score 0):

`a1.reduce(nil) {|r, k| r || a2[k]}` should do what you're asking.